# My composable view doesn't recompose itself even though state changes

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to develop sample chat app with jetpack compose and struggling with states. I have lazyColumn which contains messages. My problem is when user clicks the button, my "ChatList" function doesn't recompose eventhough my list gets update. It only recompose when "message" state changes. So i can see  previously added messages on list after i type something to texxtfield.

Here is my composables and viewmodel :

```
@Composablefun ChatList() {
ConstraintLayout {
    val (list, send) = createRefs()
    val viewModel = viewModel<MainViewModel>()
    val chatList by viewModel.messages.observeAsState(viewModel.messageList)
    var message by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
    val state = rememberLazyListState()
    LazyColumn(state = state, modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(list) {
        top.linkTo(parent.top)
        bottom.linkTo(send.top)
        height = Dimension.fillToConstraints
    }) {
        items(chatList) { item ->
            when (item.isMe) {
                true -> ChatLayoutMe(item.message)
                false -> ChatLayout(item.message)
            }
        }
    }
    SendMessage(message = message, modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(send) {
        bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
    }) {
        message = it
    }
}}

@Composablefun SendMessage(message: String, modifier: Modifier, onMessageChange: (String) -> Unit) {
    ......
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .clickable { viewModel.addMessage(message) }
        ......    
}

class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {

  val messages = MutableLiveData<List<ChatItem>>()

  val messageList = mutableListOf<ChatItem>().apply {
    ............
  }

  fun addMessage(message: String) {
     messageList.add(ChatItem(message, true))
     messages.value = messageList
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I guess your the `messageList` property is getting the same instance of the same memory address (This won't be able to - trigger - notify new data). Try changing the code inside the `addMessage` function to:

```
fun addMessage(message: String) {
    messageList.add(ChatItem(message, true))
    // messages.value = messageList
    messages.value = messageList.toMutableList() // Copy it to a new memory address
}
```

Comment: I just tried your solution but it didn't help. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Another solution, use by mutableStateOf(...) follow by https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-state?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fcompose%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fjetpack-compose-state#8

Comment: I changed my livedata to state as in codelab explained. I also passed my list in composable constructer. Nothing has changed. I wonder what i am missing..

Comment: @BerkayKireçci did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

This issue might arise if you get the same `ComposeView` attached twice to a Window, or reuse it (e.g. calling `setContentView` twice with a view hierarchy instance that contains a `ComposeView`).

There's an open issue for that: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/197773820